# (SFML 2.5.1 in VS2017) Many Unresolved External Symbol Errors

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, sfml

I'm trying to build a simple SFML program, but I keep getting these errors when I build the program. I tried Google, but the errors were always different than mine. I have SFML statically linked, here's my linker input:

> winmm.lib;sfml-system-s.lib;ws2_32.lib;sfml-network-s.lib;opengl32.lib;gdi32.lib;sfml-window-s.lib;freetype.lib;sfml-graphics-s.lib

I have the SFML_STATIC line as well. I'm not quite sure what the problem is.

Code:

```
#ifndef __IOSTREAM_H
#include <iostream>
#endif

#include "data/movement.h"
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>


int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow mainw(sf::VideoMode(512, 512), "Window");

    while (mainw.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event winEvent;
        while (mainw.pollEvent(winEvent)) 
        {
            if (winEvent.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            {
                mainw.close();
            } else;
            if (winEvent.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed) 
            {
                if (winEvent.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Up)
                {
                    upEvent();
                }
                else if (winEvent.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Down)
                {
                    downEvent();
                }
                else if (winEvent.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Left)
                {
                    leftEvent();
                }
                else if (winEvent.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Right)
                {
                    rightEvent();
                }
            }
        }
    } 

    return 0;
}
```

Errors:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_RegQueryValueExW referenced in function "class sf::String __cdecl `anonymous namespace'::getDeviceName(unsigned int,struct tagJOYCAPSW)" (?getDeviceName@?A0x8939b4a8@@YA?AVString@sf@@IUtagJOYCAPSW@@@Z)  OSTetris    C:\Users\green\Documents\GitHub\OSTetris\sfml-window-s.lib(JoystickImpl.cpp.obj)    1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_EnumDisplaySettingsW referenced in function "public: static class sf::VideoMode __cdecl sf::priv::VideoModeImpl::getDesktopMode(void)" (?getDesktopMode@VideoModeImpl@priv@sf@@SA?AVVideoMode@3@XZ)    OSTetris    C:\Users\green\Documents\GitHub\OSTetris\sfml-window-s.lib(VideoModeImpl.cpp.obj)   1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_GetDC referenced in function "public: bool __cdecl sf::priv::CursorImpl::loadFromPixels(unsigned char const *,class sf::Vector2<unsigned int>,class sf::Vector2<unsigned int>)" (?loadFromPixels@CursorImpl@priv@sf@@QEAA_NPEBEV?$Vector2@I@3@1@Z) OSTetris    C:\Users\green\Documents\GitHub\OSTetris\sfml-window-s.lib(CursorImpl.cpp.obj)  1
>
>   Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_GetDC  OSTetris    C:\Users\green\Documents\GitHub\OSTetris\sfml-window-s.lib(WglContext.cpp.obj)  1
>
>   Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_GetDC  OSTetris    C:\Users\green\Documents\GitHub\OSTetris\sfml-window-s.lib(WindowImplWin32.cpp.obj) 1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_ReleaseDC referenced in function "public: bool __cdecl sf::priv::CursorImpl::loadFromPixels(unsigned char const *,class sf::Vector2<unsigned int>,class sf::Vector2<unsigned int>)" (?loadFromPixels@CursorImpl@priv@sf@@QEAA_NPEBEV?$Vector2@I@3@1@Z) OSTetris    C:\Users\green\Documents\GitHub\OSTetris\sfml-window-s.lib(CursorImpl.cpp.obj)  1
>
>   Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_ReleaseDC  OSTetris    C:\Users\green\Documents\GitHub\OSTetris\sfml-window-s.lib(WglContext.cpp.obj)  1
>
>   Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_ReleaseDC  OSTetris    C:\Users\green\Documents\GitHub\OSTetris\sfml-window-s.lib(WindowImplWin32.cpp.obj) 1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_LoadCursorW referenced in function "public: bool __cdecl sf::priv::CursorImpl::loadFromSystem(enum sf::Cursor::Type)" (?loadFromSystem@CursorImpl@priv@sf@@QEAA_NW4Type@Cursor@3@@Z)   OSTetris    C:\Users\green\Documents\GitHub\OSTetris\sfml-window-s.lib(CursorImpl.cpp.obj)  1
>
>   Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_LoadCursorW    OSTetris    C:\Users\green\Documents\GitHub\OSTetris\sfml-window-s.lib(WindowImplWin32.cpp.obj) 1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_DestroyCursor referenced in function "public: __cdecl sf::priv::CursorImpl::~CursorImpl(void)" (??1CursorImpl@priv@sf@@QEAA@XZ)    OSTetris    C:\Users\green\Documents\GitHub\OSTetris\sfml-window-s.lib(CursorImpl.cpp.obj)  1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_CreateIconIndirect referenced in function "public: bool __cdecl sf::priv::CursorImpl::loadFromPixels(unsigned char const *,class sf::Vector2<unsigned int>,class sf::Vector2<unsigned int>)" (?loadFromPixels@CursorImpl@priv@sf@@QEAA_NPEBEV?$Vector2@I@3@1@Z)    OSTetris    C:\Users\green\Documents\GitHub\OSTetris\sfml-window-s.lib(CursorImpl.cpp.obj)  1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_CopyIcon referenced in function "public: bool __cdecl sf::priv::CursorImpl::loadFromSystem(enum sf::Cursor::Type)" (?loadFromSystem@CursorImpl@priv@sf@@QEAA_NW4Type@Cursor@3@@Z)  OSTetris    C:\Users\green\Documents\GitHub\OSTetris\sfml-window-s.lib(CursorImpl.cpp.obj)  1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_CreateWindowExA referenced in function "private: void __cdecl sf::priv::WglContext::createSurface(class sf::priv::WglContext *,unsigned int,unsigned int,unsigned int)" (?createSurface@WglContext@priv@sf@@AEAAXPEAV123@III@Z)    OSTetris    C:\Users\green\Documents\GitHub\OSTetris\sfml-window-s.lib(WglContext.cpp.obj)  1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_DestroyWindow referenced in function "public: virtual __cdecl sf::priv::WglContext::~WglContext(void)" (??1WglContext@priv@sf@@UEAA@XZ)    OSTetris    C:\Users\green\Documents\GitHub\OSTetris\sfml-window-s.lib(WglContext.cpp.obj)  1
>
>   Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_DestroyWindow  OSTetris    C:\Users\green\Documents\GitHub\OSTetris\sfml-window-s.lib(WindowImplWin32.cpp.obj) 1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_ShowWindow referenced in function "private: void __cdecl sf::priv::WglContext::createSurface(class sf::priv::WglContext *,unsigned int,unsigned int,unsigned int)" (?createSurface@WglContext@priv@sf@@AEAAXPEAV123@III@Z) OSTetris    C:\Users\green\Documents\GitHub\OSTetris\sfml-window-s.lib(WglContext.cpp.obj)  1
>
>   Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_ShowWindow OSTetris    C:\Users\green\Documents\GitHub\OSTetris\sfml-window-s.lib(WindowImplWin32.cpp.obj) 1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_TrackMouseEvent referenced in function "private: void __cdecl sf::priv::WindowImplWin32::cleanup(void)" (?cleanup@WindowImplWin32@priv@sf@@AEAAXXZ)    OSTetris    C:\Users\green\Documents\GitHub\OSTetris\sfml-window-s.lib(WindowImplWin32.cpp.obj) 1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_TranslateMessage referenced in function "protected: virtual void __cdecl sf::priv::WindowImplWin32::processEvents(void)" (?processEvents@WindowImplWin32@priv@sf@@MEAAXXZ) OSTetris    C:\Users\green\Documents\GitHub\OSTetris\sfml-window-s.lib(WindowImplWin32.cpp.obj) 1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_DispatchMessageW referenced in function "protected: virtual void __cdecl sf::priv::WindowImplWin32::processEvents(void)" (?processEvents@WindowImplWin32@priv@sf@@MEAAXXZ) OSTetris    C:\Users\green\Documents\GitHub\OSTetris\sfml-window-s.lib(WindowImplWin32.cpp.obj) 1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_PeekMessageW referenced in function "protected: virtual void __cdecl sf::priv::WindowImplWin32::processEvents(void)" (?processEvents@WindowImplWin32@priv@sf@@MEAAXXZ) OSTetris    C:\Users\green\Documents\GitHub\OSTetris\sfml-window-s.lib(WindowImplWin32.cpp.obj) 1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_SendMessageW referenced in function "public: virtual void __cdecl sf::priv::WindowImplWin32::setIcon(unsigned int,unsigned int,unsigned char const *)" (?setIcon@WindowImplWin32@priv@sf@@UEAAXIIPEBE@Z)   OSTetris    C:\Users\green\Documents\GitHub\OSTetris\sfml-window-s.lib(WindowImplWin32.cpp.obj) 1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_RegisterDeviceNotificationW referenced in function "public: __cdecl sf::priv::WindowImplWin32::WindowImplWin32(class sf::VideoMode,class sf::String const &,unsigned int,struct sf::ContextSettings const &)" (??0WindowImplWin32@priv@sf@@QEAA@VVideoMode@2@AEBVString@2@IAEBUContextSettings@2@@Z)   OSTetris    C:\Users\green\Documents\GitHub\OSTetris\sfml-window-s.lib(WindowImplWin32.cpp.obj) 1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_DefWindowProcW referenced in function "private: static __int64 __cdecl sf::priv::WindowImplWin32::globalOnEvent(struct HWND__ *,unsigned int,unsigned __int64,__int64)" (?globalOnEvent@WindowImplWin32@priv@sf@@CA_JPEAUHWND__@@I_K_J@Z)  OSTetris    C:\Users\green\Documents\GitHub\OSTetris\sfml-window-s.lib(WindowImplWin32.cpp.obj) 1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_CallWindowProcW referenced in function "private: static __int64 __cdecl sf::priv::WindowImplWin32::globalOnEvent(struct HWND__ *,unsigned int,unsigned __int64,__int64)" (?globalOnEvent@WindowImplWin32@priv@sf@@CA_JPEAUHWND__@@I_K_J@Z) OSTetris    C:\Users\green\Documents\GitHub\OSTetris\sfml-window-s.lib(WindowImplWin32.cpp.obj) 1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_RegisterClassW referenced in function "public: __cdecl sf::priv::WindowImplWin32::WindowImplWin32(class sf::VideoMode,class sf::String const &,unsigned int,struct sf::ContextSettings const &)" (??0WindowImplWin32@priv@sf@@QEAA@VVideoMode@2@AEBVString@2@IAEBUContextSettings@2@@Z)    OSTetris    C:\Users\green\Documents\GitHub\OSTetris\sfml-window-s.lib(WindowImplWin32.cpp.obj) 1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_UnregisterClassW referenced in function "public: virtual __cdecl sf::priv::WindowImplWin32::~WindowImplWin32(void)" (??1WindowImplWin32@priv@sf@@UEAA@XZ)  OSTetris    C:\Users\green\Documents\GitHub\OSTetris\sfml-window-s.lib(WindowImplWin32.cpp.obj) 1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_CreateWindowExW referenced in function "public: __cdecl sf::priv::WindowImplWin32::WindowImplWin32(class sf::VideoMode,class sf::String const &,unsigned int,struct sf::ContextSettings const &)" (??0WindowImplWin32@priv@sf@@QEAA@VVideoMode@2@AEBVString@2@IAEBUContextSettings@2@@Z)   OSTetris    C:\Users\green\Documents\GitHub\OSTetris\sfml-window-s.lib(WindowImplWin32.cpp.obj) 1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_FlashWindowEx referenced in function "public: virtual void __cdecl sf::priv::WindowImplWin32::requestFocus(void)" (?requestFocus@WindowImplWin32@priv@sf@@UEAAXXZ) OSTetris    C:\Users\green\Documents\GitHub\OSTetris\sfml-window-s.lib(WindowImplWin32.cpp.obj) 1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_SetWindowPos referenced in function "public: __cdecl sf::priv::WindowImplWin32::WindowImplWin32(class sf::VideoMode,class sf::String const &,unsigned int,struct sf::ContextSettings const &)" (??0WindowImplWin32@priv@sf@@QEAA@VVideoMode@2@AEBVString@2@IAEBUContextSettings@2@@Z)  OSTetris    C:\Users\green\Documents\GitHub\OSTetris\sfml-window-s.lib(WindowImplWin32.cpp.obj) 1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_GetKeyState referenced in function "private: void __cdecl sf::priv::WindowImplWin32::processEvent(unsigned int,unsigned __int64,__int64)" (?processEvent@WindowImplWin32@priv@sf@@AEAAXI_K_J@Z)    OSTetris    C:\Users\green\Documents\GitHub\OSTetris\sfml-window-s.lib(WindowImplWin32.cpp.obj) 1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_MapVirtualKeyW referenced in function "private: static enum sf::Keyboard::Key __cdecl sf::priv::WindowImplWin32::virtualKeyCodeToSF(unsigned __int64,__int64)" (?virtualKeyCodeToSF@WindowImplWin32@priv@sf@@CA?AW4Key@Keyboard@3@_K_J@Z)  OSTetris    C:\Users\green\Documents\GitHub\OSTetris\sfml-window-s.lib(WindowImplWin32.cpp.obj) 1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_GetCapture referenced in function "private: void __cdecl sf::priv::WindowImplWin32::processEvent(unsigned int,unsigned __int64,__int64)" (?processEvent@WindowImplWin32@priv@sf@@AEAAXI_K_J@Z) OSTetris    C:\Users\green\Documents\GitHub\OSTetris\sfml-window-s.lib(WindowImplWin32.cpp.obj) 1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_SetCapture referenced in function "private: void __cdecl sf::priv::WindowImplWin32::processEvent(unsigned int,unsigned __int64,__int64)" (?processEvent@WindowImplWin32@priv@sf@@AEAAXI_K_J@Z) OSTetris    C:\Users\green\Documents\GitHub\OSTetris\sfml-window-s.lib(WindowImplWin32.cpp.obj) 1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_ReleaseCapture referenced in function "private: void __cdecl sf::priv::WindowImplWin32::cleanup(void)" (?cleanup@WindowImplWin32@priv@sf@@AEAAXXZ) OSTetris    C:\Users\green\Documents\GitHub\OSTetris\sfml-window-s.lib(WindowImplWin32.cpp.obj) 1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_GetForegroundWindow referenced in function "public: virtual bool __cdecl sf::priv::WindowImplWin32::hasFocus(void)const " (?hasFocus@WindowImplWin32@priv@sf@@UEBA_NXZ)    OSTetris    C:\Users\green\Documents\GitHub\OSTetris\sfml-window-s.lib(WindowImplWin32.cpp.obj) 1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_SetForegroundWindow referenced in function "public: virtual void __cdecl sf::priv::WindowImplWin32::requestFocus(void)" (?requestFocus@WindowImplWin32@priv@sf@@UEAAXXZ)   OSTetris    C:\Users\green\Documents\GitHub\OSTetris\sfml-window-s.lib(WindowImplWin32.cpp.obj) 1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_SetWindowTextW referenced in function "public: virtual void __cdecl sf::priv::WindowImplWin32::setTitle(class sf::String const &)" (?setTitle@WindowImplWin32@priv@sf@@UEAAXAEBVString@3@@Z)   OSTetris    C:\Users\green\Documents\GitHub\OSTetris\sfml-window-s.lib(WindowImplWin32.cpp.obj) 1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_GetClientRect referenced in function "public: virtual class sf::Vector2<unsigned int> __cdecl sf::priv::WindowImplWin32::getSize(void)const " (?getSize@WindowImplWin32@priv@sf@@UEBA?AV?$Vector2@I@3@XZ)  OSTetris    C:\Users\green\Documents\GitHub\OSTetris\sfml-window-s.lib(WindowImplWin32.cpp.obj) 1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_GetWindowRect referenced in function "public: virtual class sf::Vector2<int> __cdecl sf::priv::WindowImplWin32::getPosition(void)const " (?getPosition@WindowImplWin32@priv@sf@@UEBA?AV?$Vector2@H@3@XZ)   OSTetris    C:\Users\green\Documents\GitHub\OSTetris\sfml-window-s.lib(WindowImplWin32.cpp.obj) 1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_AdjustWindowRect referenced in function "public: __cdecl sf::priv::WindowImplWin32::WindowImplWin32(class sf::VideoMode,class sf::String const &,unsigned int,struct sf::ContextSettings const &)" (??0WindowImplWin32@priv@sf@@QEAA@VVideoMode@2@AEBVString@2@IAEBUContextSettings@2@@Z)  OSTetris    C:\Users\green\Documents\GitHub\OSTetris\sfml-window-s.lib(WindowImplWin32.cpp.obj) 1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_ShowCursor referenced in function "public: virtual void __cdecl sf::priv::WindowImplWin32::setMouseCursorVisible(bool)" (?setMouseCursorVisible@WindowImplWin32@priv@sf@@UEAAX_N@Z)    OSTetris    C:\Users\green\Documents\GitHub\OSTetris\sfml-window-s.lib(WindowImplWin32.cpp.obj) 1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_SetCursor referenced in function "private: void __cdecl sf::priv::WindowImplWin32::processEvent(unsigned int,unsigned __int64,__int64)" (?processEvent@WindowImplWin32@priv@sf@@AEAAXI_K_J@Z)  OSTetris    C:\Users\green\Documents\GitHub\OSTetris\sfml-window-s.lib(WindowImplWin32.cpp.obj) 1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_ScreenToClient referenced in function "private: void __cdecl sf::priv::WindowImplWin32::processEvent(unsigned int,unsigned __int64,__int64)" (?processEvent@WindowImplWin32@priv@sf@@AEAAXI_K_J@Z) OSTetris    C:\Users\green\Documents\GitHub\OSTetris\sfml-window-s.lib(WindowImplWin32.cpp.obj) 1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_MapWindowPoints referenced in function "private: void __cdecl sf::priv::WindowImplWin32::grabCursor(bool)" (?grabCursor@WindowImplWin32@priv@sf@@AEAAX_N@Z)    OSTetris    C:\Users\green\Documents\GitHub\OSTetris\sfml-window-s.lib(WindowImplWin32.cpp.obj) 1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_ClipCursor referenced in function "private: void __cdecl sf::priv::WindowImplWin32::grabCursor(bool)" (?grabCursor@WindowImplWin32@priv@sf@@AEAAX_N@Z) OSTetris    C:\Users\green\Documents\GitHub\OSTetris\sfml-window-s.lib(WindowImplWin32.cpp.obj) 1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_GetWindowLongW referenced in function "public: __cdecl sf::priv::WindowImplWin32::WindowImplWin32(class sf::VideoMode,class sf::String const &,unsigned int,struct sf::ContextSettings const &)" (??0WindowImplWin32@priv@sf@@QEAA@VVideoMode@2@AEBVString@2@IAEBUContextSettings@2@@Z)    OSTetris    C:\Users\green\Documents\GitHub\OSTetris\sfml-window-s.lib(WindowImplWin32.cpp.obj) 1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_SetWindowLongW referenced in function "public: __cdecl sf::priv::WindowImplWin32::WindowImplWin32(class sf::VideoMode,class sf::String const &,unsigned int,struct sf::ContextSettings const &)" (??0WindowImplWin32@priv@sf@@QEAA@VVideoMode@2@AEBVString@2@IAEBUContextSettings@2@@Z)    OSTetris    C:\Users\green\Documents\GitHub\OSTetris\sfml-window-s.lib(WindowImplWin32.cpp.obj) 1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_GetWindowLongPtrW referenced in function "private: static __int64 __cdecl sf::priv::WindowImplWin32::globalOnEvent(struct HWND__ *,unsigned int,unsigned __int64,__int64)" (?globalOnEvent@WindowImplWin32@priv@sf@@CA_JPEAUHWND__@@I_K_J@Z)   OSTetris    C:\Users\green\Documents\GitHub\OSTetris\sfml-window-s.lib(WindowImplWin32.cpp.obj) 1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_SetWindowLongPtrW referenced in function "public: __cdecl sf::priv::WindowImplWin32::WindowImplWin32(struct HWND__ *)" (??0WindowImplWin32@priv@sf@@QEAA@PEAUHWND__@@@Z)   OSTetris    C:\Users\green\Documents\GitHub\OSTetris\sfml-window-s.lib(WindowImplWin32.cpp.obj) 1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_GetWindowThreadProcessId referenced in function "public: virtual void __cdecl sf::priv::WindowImplWin32::requestFocus(void)" (?requestFocus@WindowImplWin32@priv@sf@@UEAAXXZ)  OSTetris    C:\Users\green\Documents\GitHub\OSTetris\sfml-window-s.lib(WindowImplWin32.cpp.obj) 1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_CreateIcon referenced in function "public: virtual void __cdecl sf::priv::WindowImplWin32::setIcon(unsigned int,unsigned int,unsigned char const *)" (?setIcon@WindowImplWin32@priv@sf@@UEAAXIIPEBE@Z) OSTetris    C:\Users\green\Documents\GitHub\OSTetris\sfml-window-s.lib(WindowImplWin32.cpp.obj) 1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_DestroyIcon referenced in function "public: virtual __cdecl sf::priv::WindowImplWin32::~WindowImplWin32(void)" (??1WindowImplWin32@priv@sf@@UEAA@XZ)   OSTetris    C:\Users\green\Documents\GitHub\OSTetris\sfml-window-s.lib(WindowImplWin32.cpp.obj) 1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_ChangeDisplaySettingsW referenced in function "public: __cdecl sf::priv::WindowImplWin32::WindowImplWin32(class sf::VideoMode,class sf::String const &,unsigned int,struct sf::ContextSettings const &)" (??0WindowImplWin32@priv@sf@@QEAA@VVideoMode@2@AEBVString@2@IAEBUContextSettings@2@@Z)    OSTetris    C:\Users\green\Documents\GitHub\OSTetris\sfml-window-s.lib(WindowImplWin32.cpp.obj) 1
>
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_RegCloseKey referenced in function "class sf::String __cdecl`anonymous namespace'::getDeviceName(unsigned int,struct tagJOYCAPSW)" (?getDeviceName@?A0x8939b4a8@@YA?AVString@sf@@IUtagJOYCAPSW@@@Z)   OSTetris    C:\Users\green\Documents\GitHub\OSTetris\sfml-window-s.lib(JoystickImpl.cpp.obj)    1
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_RegOpenKeyExW referenced in function "class sf::String __cdecl `anonymous namespace'::getDeviceName(unsigned int,struct tagJOYCAPSW)" (?getDeviceName@?A0x8939b4a8@@YA?AVString@sf@@IUtagJOYCAPSW@@@Z) OSTetris    C:\Users\green\Documents\GitHub\OSTetris\sfml-window-s.lib(JoystickImpl.cpp.obj)    1
>   Error   LNK1120 50 unresolved externals OSTetris    C:\Users\green\Documents\GitHub\OSTetris\x64\Release\OSTetris.exe   1

Answer (score 0):

First I am going to link to [SFML's tutorial page for Visual Studio linking](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/start-vc.php).

But it looks like you only link the release versions. Make sure you use the Debug libs under the Debug configuration and the Release libs under the Release configuration. Each configuration needs setup individually.

Answer (score 0):

When you're in your project properties, you have a drop down that you can select "all configs" or "debug" or "release"...etc.

You need to link the libs with the name sfml-window-s-d.lib (note the "d" for debug)
When you do the release version you need to remove the "d".

Also do not forget the "SFML_STATIC" macro which is needed when you're linking to the static version of the library... which if you have a -s in your lib name then you're using the static version.

I would suggest setting up all the includes and links under debug alone, then switch the dropdown to release and do it all again making sure you include the -d only in debug. Make sure you do all of the steps for both if you plan on using both debug and release builds.

Make sure you read: https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/start-vc.php very, very carefully.

Also make sure you are linking the extra libs it lists if needed (opengl32.lib, winmm.lib and gdi32.lib) and also freetype.lib or openal.lib if you're using fonts or audio.

And if you're using a console based program, make sure your main entry is int main and not winmain and your subsystem is set to console and not windows.